# Busca unica mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estou fazendo uma busca no db que precisa retomar a soma de um campo e o ultimo valor correspondente, e agrupando-os á um índice

Query

```
  $stmt = getConn()->query("SELECT senha,movi,SUM(entrada) as entrada,custo FROM estoquemovimento ORDER BY id DESC");
  $items = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP | PDO::FETCH_ASSOC | PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);
```

Resposta

```
Array
(
    [NbpsCQAMyc] => Array
        (
            [movi] => Adicionado
            [entrada] => 2.000
            [custo] => 3.00
        )

)
```

esta tudo correto, na formatação do array, apenas o custo esta buscando o do primeiro registo, e não o referente ao ultimo registro

preciso que a busca retorne o custo referente ao ultimo registro

Comment: usa o LIMIT 1, assim só pega um registo

Comment: mesmo com LIMIT 1, retorna o custo referente ao primeiro registro

Comment: sim, pq custo e o valor atual da ultiam compra, é entrada e todo o peso que entrou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### EDIT #1

Como visto pelo autor da pergunta, o `MariaDB` ignora o `ORDER BY` em subquery:
[Why is ORDER BY in a FROM Subquery Ignored?](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/)

A solução é utilizar um `LIMIT` que busque todos os registros:

```
SELECT SUM(entrada) as entrada,custo 
FROM (SELECT * FROM estoquemovimento ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 999999999) alias_tab
```

Ou um `JOIN`: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481867/order-by-is-being-ignored-in-subquery-join)

---

O `ORDER BY` é **aplicado no retorno da sua query**, ou seja, no resultado. Então ele está ordenando por `id` o seu retorno, que neste caso, é somente 1 linha.

Uma opção é por `subquery`, ordenando antes e fazendo o select no resultado:

```
SELECT SUM(entrada) as entrada,custo
FROM (SELECT * FROM estoquemovimento ORDER BY id DESC) alias_tab
```

[Exemplo no SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/892740/7)

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79768/discussion-on-answer-by-rbz-busca-unica-mysql)